# CrossroadsSlides not working after AJAX load, starts working only when resize the page

Tags: ajax, slider, resize, load

1. I'm trying to get this slider to work after AJAX load, it starts working if you manually do resize page
2. https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/04/03/crossroads-slideshow/
3. below is the main code I am using in JS file
4. I am using this code to show my content with slider `$('.cd-folding-panel').addClass('is-open'); $('.cd-main').addClass('fold-is-open'); }, 100);` and when the slider appears it seems to be frozen, and it starts working when i resize the broweser, please help

```
{
    const MathUtils = {
        lineEq: (y2, y1, x2, x1, currentVal) => {
            // y = mx + b 
            var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1), b = y1 - m * x1;
            return m * currentVal + b;
        },
        lerp: (a, b, n) => (1 - n) * a + n * b,
        distance: (x1, x2, y1, y2) => {
            var a = x1 - x2;
            var b = y1 - y2;
            return Math.hypot(a, b);
        },
        randomNumber: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    };

    let winsize;
    const calcWinsize = () => winsize = { width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight };
    calcWinsize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', calcWinsize);

    const getMousePos = (ev) => {
        let posx = 0;
        let posy = 0;
        if (!ev) ev = window.event;
        if (ev.pageX || ev.pageY) {
            posx = ev.pageX;
            posy = ev.pageY;
        }
        else if (ev.clientX || ev.clientY) {
            posx = ev.clientX + body.scrollLeft + docEl.scrollLeft;
            posy = ev.clientY + body.scrollTop + docEl.scrollTop;
        }
        return { x: posx, y: posy };
    }

    let mousePos = { x: winsize.width / 2, y: winsize.height / 2 };
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => mousePos = getMousePos(ev));

    class Slide {
        constructor(el, title) {
            this.DOM = { el: el };
            this.DOM.title = title;
            charming(this.DOM.title);
            this.DOM.titleLetters = [...this.DOM.title.querySelectorAll('span')];
            this.DOM.titleLetters.sort(() => Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
            this.DOM.number = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.number');
            this.DOM.subtitle = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.caption');
            this.DOM.imgWrap = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.img-wrap');
            this.DOM.img = this.DOM.imgWrap.querySelector('.img');
        }
        move(direction, val) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const tx = direction === 'left' ? '+=' + val * -1 : '+=' + val;
                const duration = 1.2;

                new TimelineMax({ onComplete: resolve })
                    .to(this.DOM.imgWrap, duration, {
                        x: tx,
                        ease: Quart.easeInOut
                    }, 0)
                    .to(this.DOM.imgWrap, duration * .5, {
                        scaleX: 1.3,
                        ease: Quart.easeIn
                    }, 0)
                    .to(this.DOM.imgWrap, duration * .5, {
                        scaleX: 1,
                        ease: Quart.easeOut
                    }, duration * .5)
                    .to(this.DOM.number, duration * .95, {
                        x: tx,
                        ease: Quint.easeInOut
                    }, 0)
                    .to(this.DOM.subtitle, duration * 1.1, {
                        x: tx,
                        ease: Quart.easeInOut
                    }, 0)
                    .to(this.DOM.title, duration * 1.05, {
                        x: tx,
                        ease: Quart.easeInOut
                    }, 0);
            });
        }
        setCenter() {
            this.isCenter = true;
            this.DOM.el.classList.add('grid__item--center');
            this.DOM.title.classList.add('grid__item--center');
            TweenMax.set([this.DOM.el, this.DOM.title], { opacity: 1 });
        }
        setRight() {
            this.isRight = this.isCenter = false;
            this.isLeft = true;
            this.DOM.el.classList.add('grid__item--right');
            this.DOM.title.classList.add('grid__item--right');
            TweenMax.set([this.DOM.el, this.DOM.title], { opacity: 1 });
        }
        setLeft() {
            this.isLeft = this.isCenter = false;
            this.isRight = true;
            this.DOM.el.classList.add('grid__item--left');
            this.DOM.title.classList.add('grid__item--left');
            TweenMax.set([this.DOM.el, this.DOM.title], { opacity: 1 });
        }
        reset() {
            TweenMax.set([this.DOM.el, this.DOM.imgWrap, this.DOM.number, this.DOM.subtitle, this.DOM.title], { transform: 'none' });
            TweenMax.set([this.DOM.el, this.DOM.title], { opacity: 0 });
            this.DOM.title.classList = 'grid__item grid__item--title';
            this.DOM.el.classList = 'grid__item grid__item--slide';
        }
        animateElementsOut(contentItem) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const time = MathUtils.randomNumber(0, 100) / 500;
                this.elemsTimeline = new TimelineMax({ onComplete: resolve })
                    .staggerTo(this.DOM.titleLetters, 1, {
                        y: MathUtils.randomNumber(300, 600),
                        opacity: 0,
                        ease: Quart.easeInOut
                    }, 0.04, time)
                    .staggerTo(this.DOM.titleLetters, 0.5, {
                        scaleY: 2.2,
                        ease: Quart.easeIn
                    }, 0.04, time)
                    .staggerTo(this.DOM.titleLetters, 0.5, {
                        scaleY: 1,
                        ease: Quart.easeOut
                    }, 0.04, time + 0.5)
                    .to(this.DOM.number, 1, {
                        y: -500,
                        opacity: 0,
                        ease: Quart.easeInOut
                    }, time + 0.3)
                    .to(this.DOM.imgWrap, 0.8, {
                        y: -500,
                        opacity: 0,
                        ease: Quart.easeInOut
                    }, time + 0.4)
                    .to(this.DOM.imgWrap, .4, {
                        scaleX: 0.95,
                        scaleY: 1.4,
                        ease: Quart.easeIn
                    }, time + 0.4)
                    .to(this.DOM.imgWrap, .4, {
                        scaleX: 1,
                        scaleY: 1,
                        ease: Quart.easeOut
                    }, time + 0.4 + 0.4)
                    .to(this.DOM.subtitle, 1, {
                        y: -500,
                        opacity: 0,
                        ease: Quart.easeInOut
                    }, time + 0.5);

                if (this.isCenter) {
                    const contentItemTitle = contentItem.querySelector('.content__item-header-title');
                    const contentItemImg = contentItem.querySelector('.img--content');
                    this.elemsTimeline.to(contentItemTitle, 0.8, {
                        ease: Expo.easeOut,
                        startAt: { y: '100%', opacity: 0, rotation: -16 },
                        y: '0%',
                        rotation: 0,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, time + 1.3)
                        .set(contentItemImg, { scale: 1.2 }, 0)
                        .to(contentItemImg, 0.8, {
                            ease: Expo.easeOut,
                            scale: 1
                        }, time + 1.3)
                        .to(revealer.DOM.el, 1, {
                            ease: Quint.easeOut,
                            y: '-100%'
                        }, time + 1.2);
                }
            });
        }
        animateElementsIn(contentItem) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const time = MathUtils.randomNumber(0, 50) / 500;
                this.elemsTimeline = new TimelineMax({ onComplete: resolve });

                if (this.isCenter) {
                    const contentItemTitle = contentItem.querySelector('.content__item-header-title');
                    const contentItemImg = contentItem.querySelector('.img--content');
                    this.elemsTimeline.to(contentItemTitle, 1, {
                        ease: Quint.easeOut,
                        y: '50%',
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 0)
                        .to(contentItemImg, 1, {
                            ease: Quint.easeOut,
                            scale: 1.2
                        }, 0)
                        .to(revealer.DOM.el, 1, {
                            ease: Quint.easeOut,
                            y: '0%'
                        }, 0);
                }
                this.elemsTimeline.to(this.DOM.subtitle, 0.8, {
                    y: 0,
                    opacity: 1,
                    ease: Quart.easeOut
                }, time)
                    .to(this.DOM.imgWrap, 0.8, {
                        y: 0,
                        opacity: 1,
                        scaleX: 1,
                        scaleY: 1,
                        ease: Quart.easeOut
                    }, time + 0.1)
                    .to(this.DOM.number, 0.8, {
                        y: 0,
                        opacity: 1,
                        ease: Quart.easeOut
                    }, time + 0.2)
                    .staggerTo(this.DOM.titleLetters, 0.8, {
                        y: 0,
                        opacity: 1,
                        scaleX: 1,
                        scaleY: 1,
                        ease: Quart.easeOut
                    }, 0.03, time + 0.1)
            });
        }
    }


    class Slideshow {
        constructor(el) {
            this.DOM = { el: el };
            // The titles
            this.DOM.titlesWrap = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.titles-wrap');
            this.DOM.titlesInner = this.DOM.titlesWrap.querySelector('.grid--titles');
            this.DOM.titles = [...this.DOM.titlesInner.querySelectorAll('.grid__item--title')];
            // The slides instances
            this.slides = [];
            [...this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.grid__item--slide')].forEach((slide, pos) => this.slides.push(new Slide(slide, this.DOM.titles[pos])));
            // Total number of slides
            this.slidesTotal = this.slides.length;
            if (this.slidesTotal < 4) return;
            // Center slide's position
            this.center = 0;

            // Content Items
            this.DOM.contentItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.content__item')];

            // Areas (left, center, right) where to attach the navigation events.
            this.DOM.interaction = {
                left: document.querySelector('.grid__item--left'),
                center: document.querySelector('.grid__item--center'),
                right: document.querySelector('.grid__item--right')
            };

            this.setVisibleSlides();
            this.calculateGap();
            this.initEvents();

            let mouseMoveVals = { translation: 0, rotation: -8 };
            const render = () => {
                //if ( !this.isAnimating ) {
                mouseMoveVals.translation = MathUtils.lerp(mouseMoveVals.translation, MathUtils.lineEq(-15, 15, winsize.width, 0, mousePos.x), 0.03);
                //mouseMoveVals.rotation = MathUtils.lerp(mouseMoveVals.rotation, MathUtils.lineEq(-8.5, -7.5, winsize.width, 0, mousePos.x), 0.03);
                for (let i = 0; i <= this.slidesTotal - 1; ++i) {
                    TweenMax.set(this.slides[i].DOM.img, { x: mouseMoveVals.translation });
                    TweenMax.set(this.DOM.titlesInner, { x: -4 * mouseMoveVals.translation });
                    //TweenMax.set(this.DOM.el, {rotation: mouseMoveVals.rotation});
                    //TweenMax.set(this.DOM.titlesWrap, {rotation: -2*mouseMoveVals.rotation});
                }
                //}
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
        setVisibleSlides() {
            this.centerSlide = this.slides[this.center];
            this.rightSlide = this.slides[this.center + 1 <= this.slidesTotal - 1 ? this.center + 1 : 0];
            this.leftSlide = this.slides[this.center - 1 >= 0 ? this.center - 1 : this.slidesTotal - 1];
            this.centerSlide.setCenter();
            this.rightSlide.setRight();
            this.leftSlide.setLeft();
        }
        // Distance between 2 slides 
        // The amount to translate the elements that move when we navigate the slideshow
        calculateGap() {
            const s1 = this.slides[0].DOM.el.getBoundingClientRect();
            const s2 = this.slides[1].DOM.el.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.gap = MathUtils.distance(s1.left + s1.width / 2, s2.left + s2.width / 2, s1.top + s1.height / 2, s2.top + s2.height / 2);
        }
        // Initialize events
        initEvents() {
            this.clickRightFn = () => this.navigate('right');
            this.DOM.interaction.right.addEventListener('click', this.clickRightFn);

            this.clickLeftFn = () => this.navigate('left');
            this.DOM.interaction.left.addEventListener('click', this.clickLeftFn);

            this.clickCenterFn = () => this.openSlide();
            this.DOM.interaction.center.addEventListener('click', this.clickCenterFn);

            this.mouseenterCenterFn = () => {
                if (this.isAnimating) {
                    return;
                }
                new TimelineMax()
                    .to(this.centerSlide.DOM.imgWrap, 0.7, {
                        ease: Expo.easeOut,
                        scale: 1.02
                    })
                    .to(this.centerSlide.DOM.img, 1.7, {
                        ease: Expo.easeOut,
                        scale: 1.05
                    }, 0);
            };
            this.DOM.interaction.center.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseenterCenterFn);

            this.mouseleaveCenterFn = () => {
                if (this.isAnimating) {
                    return;
                }
                new TimelineMax().to(this.centerSlide.DOM.imgWrap, 0.7, {
                    ease: Expo.easeOut,
                    scale: 1
                })
                    .to(this.centerSlide.DOM.img, 0.7, {
                        ease: Expo.easeOut,
                        scale: 1
                    }, 0);
            };
            this.DOM.interaction.center.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseleaveCenterFn);

            this.resizeFn = () => this.calculateGap();
            window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeFn);

            this.DOM.contentItems.forEach(item => {
                item.querySelector('.img-wrap--content').addEventListener('click', () => this.closeSlide());
            });
        }
        navigate(direction) {
            if (this.isAnimating) {
                return false;
            }
            this.isAnimating = true;

            const upcomingPos = direction === 'right' ?
                this.center < this.slidesTotal - 2 ? this.center + 2 : Math.abs(this.slidesTotal - 2 - this.center) :
                this.center >= 2 ? this.center - 2 : Math.abs(this.slidesTotal - 2 + this.center);

            // Update current.
            this.center = direction === 'right' ?
                this.center < this.slidesTotal - 1 ? this.center + 1 : 0 :
                this.center > 0 ? this.center - 1 : this.slidesTotal - 1;

            this.upcomingSlide = this.slides[upcomingPos];
            this.upcomingTitle = this.upcomingSlide.DOM.title;
            // Position upcomingSlide / upcomingTitle
            TweenMax.set(this.upcomingSlide.DOM.el, { x: direction === 'right' ? this.gap * 2 : -1 * this.gap * 2, opacity: 1 });
            TweenMax.set(this.upcomingTitle, { x: direction === 'right' ? this.gap * 2 : -1 * this.gap * 2, opacity: 1 });

            const movingSlides = [this.upcomingSlide, this.centerSlide, this.rightSlide, this.leftSlide];
            let promises = [];
            movingSlides.forEach(slide => promises.push(slide.move(direction === 'right' ? 'left' : 'right', this.gap)));
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                // After all is moved, update the classes of the 3 visible slides and reset styles
                movingSlides.forEach(slide => slide.reset());
                // Set it again
                this.setVisibleSlides();
                this.isAnimating = false;
            });
        }
        openSlide() {
            this.toggleSlide('open');
        }
        closeSlide() {
            this.toggleSlide('close');
        }
        toggleSlide(action) {
            if (this.isAnimating) {
                return;
            }
            this.isAnimating = true;

            const contentItem = this.DOM.contentItems[this.center];
            // Cursor styles related class
            this.DOM.el.classList[action === 'open' ? 'add' : 'remove']('content-open');

            const movingSlides = [this.centerSlide, this.rightSlide, this.leftSlide];
            let promises = [];
            movingSlides.forEach(slide => promises.push(slide[action === 'open' ? 'animateElementsOut' : 'animateElementsIn'](contentItem)));

            if (action === 'open') {
                contentItem.classList.add('content__item--current');
            }
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                if (action === 'close') {
                    contentItem.classList.remove('content__item--current');
                }
                this.isAnimating = false;
            });
        }
    }

    class Revealer {
        constructor(el) {
            this.DOM = { el: el };
            this.DOM.el.style.width = `calc(100vw * ${Math.cos(8 * Math.PI / 180)} + 100vh * ${Math.sin(8 * Math.PI / 180)})`;
            this.DOM.el.style.height = `calc(100vw * ${Math.sin(8 * Math.PI / 180)} + 100vh * ${Math.cos(8 * Math.PI / 180)})`;
        }
    }

    // Revealer element
    const revealer = new Revealer(document.querySelector('.revealer__inner'));
    // Initialize the slideshow
    new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.grid--slideshow'));

    // Preload all the images in the page
    imagesLoaded(document.querySelectorAll('.img'), { background: true }, () => document.body.classList.remove('loading'));

    [...document.querySelectorAll('.frame__mode input[type="radio"]')].forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.body.classList[radio.parentNode.classList.contains('frame__mode-item--dark') ? 'add' : 'remove']('dark-mode');
    }));

}
```

Comment: overal formating

Answer (score 0):

I want to do resize with code, something like this :

```
jQuery('.fullWidth').css({
        'height': browserheight,
        'width':browserwidth
});
    var browserheight = jQuery(window).height() -118; 
      jQuery('.fullWidth').css({
        'height': browserheight
});
```